# TV-series with wizards and swords, with fat companion

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a live-action TV series from the late 70's or early-mid 80's. I saw some episodes, translated into Spanish. The title was something akin to "Wizards and swords" (or any other combination of similar terms).

The main characters were a strong, tall, good-looking (probably), perhaps blonde, sword wielder man, and his companion a robust (fat?) man. Let's call them *Muscle* and *Robust*, respectively.

There is one episode I remember. It was night I think, both were tied to posts, with a grim prospect awaiting. Some monster (?) was coming, called "Bone Breaker" ("quebrantahuesos" in Spanish). Muscle tries to convince/cajole Robust to try to break the posts and set them free, with no success... Until Muscle says "you will no longer eat X (or X's?) food", to which Robust makes the effort, breaks the post, and eventually happy ending.

Any idea what could this have been?

Answer (score 26):

Possibly [Wizards and Warriors](https://nostalgiacentral.com/television/tv-by-decade/tv-shows-1980s/wizards-warriors/) from 1983?

Prince Erik Greystone was the heroic lead character, with his sidekick Marko backing him up.  It lasted only eight episodes.

[image]

Your "quebrantahuesos" is likely the Bonecrack demon in episode 2.
It ties them to trees.  Erik convinces Marko to pull his tree down, telling him that if the demon kills them then Marko "will never eat again".

The entire series is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/wizards-and-warriors-season-1-tv-series-mkv).

Comment: Oh man, that show was so bad.  It didn't take itself at all seriously, but I'm not sure whether that made it better or worse.

Comment: Billed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_and_Warriors_(TV_series)  as a "comedy adventure fantasy series"

Comment: Jeff Conway made a great gang member in Grease, security officer on Babylon-5, taxi driver on Taxi, and even besieged suburban husband in Almost Pregnant. But heroic knight is one whale of a mistcast for him.

Comment: Was there a scene in this where someone was drinking out of a skull by any chance?  Some TV show burned that into my kid brain.

Comment: @JimmyJames Tasty cranial beverages are at the 17 minute mark of episode 1.

Comment: That is definitely it.  It's almost exactly as I remembered.  Awesome find.